# Ambiguous type error & Multiple different random values in the same function

Tags: haskell, random, types, io

I need multiple random numbers in different ranges (which could be avoided by multiplying the result of the random number generator with a constant).

I'm making an Asteroid clone in Haskell, and I want to generate randomly spawned enemies. I want to let them spawn at the edge of the screen with the same velocity (so norm of velocity vector equal).

Additional info: When an entity hits the edge of the screen it appears again at the other side, this is why I chose to only let enemies spawn at two of four edges of the screen and made the velocity really determine where you first see them appear.

I looked at `System.Random` and ran into difficulties. I figured I needed five random numbers:

1. A random number to determine if at this frame a monster should
   spawn.
2. Random x position or random y position (spawns at the edge
3. Random number to determine on which side of the screen an enemy spawns
4. Random number for x velocity
5. Random number (1 or -1) to create a velocity vector with a set norm.

At the start of the game I generate a new StdGen and after that I do this every frame.

Solutions I thought of but thought were bad practice: Instead of passing down generators through methods, create a new generator every time using `newStdGen`.

I also thought of calling the newRand function for all the random numbers I need. But if I had a function that required two random numbers in the same range, the two random numbers would be identical, since identical input always gives identical output in Haskell.

**Problem: Ambiguous type variables at all the random calls except for the call to the newRand function (that is also used to update the generator each frame), because Haskell doesn't know which type of number to use.**

Sample error:

```
src\Controller.hs:45:56: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from the literal `0.0'
      prevents the constraint `(Fractional a0)' from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        axis :: a0 (bound at src\Controller.hs:45:25)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance HasResolution a => Fractional (Fixed a)
          -- Defined in `Data.Fixed'
        instance Fractional Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        instance Fractional Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
        ...plus three instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: 0.0
      In the first argument of `randomR', namely `(0.0, 1.0)'
      In the second argument of `($)', namely `randomR (0.0, 1.0) gen'
   |
45 |                         axis = signum $ fst $ randomR (0.0, 1.0) gen
   |                                                        ^^^
```

My code:

```
newRand :: StdGen -> (Float, Float) -> (Float, StdGen)
newRand gen (a, b) = randomR (a, b) gen

genEnemies :: StdGen -> Float -> [Moving Enemy]
genEnemies gen time | rand > 995 = [Moving (x, y) (vx, vy) defaultEnemy]
                    | otherwise  = []
                  where rand = fst $ newRand (0, 1000) gen
                        x | axis < 0.5  = fst $ randomR (0.0, width) gen
                          | otherwise   = 0
                        y | axis >= 0.5 = fst $ randomR (0.0, height) gen
                          | otherwise   = 0
                        axis = signum $ fst $ randomR (0.0, 1.0) gen
                        vx   = fst $ randomR (-20.0, 20.0) gen
                        vy   = sgn * sqrt (400 - vx*vx)                  
                        sgn  = (signum $ fst $ randomR (-1.0, 1.0) gen)
```

Comment: Did you try adding a type annotation as the error suggested? Is there something in particular about the message that you're confused by?

Comment: I don't know how to add a type signature to a function call. And randomR is a library function so that one already has a type signature

Comment: Errors aside, reusing the same `gen` that many times is wrong. For instance `fst $ randomR (0.0, 1.0) gen` will return the same number, when used many times. There's a reason why `randomR` returns a pair with a _new_ `gen`: so that the old `gen` can be forgotten and new numbers are taken using the new ones. You need to "chain" an pass around your `gen`s (or use a monad for that).

Comment: You can add a signature to ambiguous numbers writing e.g. `(0.0 :: Float)` instead of simply `0.0`.

Comment: I think I understand monads, but applying them myself remains difficult. could you give an answer that uses monads?

Comment: @chi How do I chain and pass the gen in the same function, I don't see how

Comment: @chi I used the monad now, but I still have the same generator all the time so I can't generate multiple random numbers in the same frame it seems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual pattern when you want to generate multiple random numbers in Haskell goes like this:

```
foo :: StdGen -> (StdGen, (Int, Int, Int))
foo g0 = let
    (val1, g1) = randomR (0, 10) g0
    (val2, g2) = randomR (0, 10) g1
    (val3, g3) = randomR (0, 10) g2
    in (g3, (val1, val2, val3))
```

For example, in ghci:

```
System.Random> foo (mkStdGen 0)
(1346387765 2103410263,(7,10,2))
```

You can see it returned three different numbers -- unlike what you would get if you called `randomR` with `g0` each time as you did in your code.

Hopefully you catch the pattern: call `randomR` with the range you want and a `StdGen`; use the value it returned as your random piece and the `StdGen` it returned as the input next time you call `randomR`. It's also important that you return the updated `StdGen` from your random function, so that you can continue the pattern in later calls.

Later you can look into monads, specifically [`RandT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Random-Lazy.html), which can abstract away the process of feeding the most recently updated `StdGen` into the next call to `randomR`. A sample of the `RandT` style looks like this:

```
foo' :: MonadRandom m => m (Int, Int, Int)
foo' = do
    val1 <- getRandomR (0, 10)
    val2 <- getRandomR (0, 10)
    val3 <- getRandomR (0, 10)
    return (val1, val2, val3)
```

...but for now, stick with the basics. Once you understand them thoroughly it will feel much less magical when you implement (or reuse) the abstractions that let you do that kind of thing.

Comment: I think it works now. Did you mean that I should use the example snippet in my `getEnemies` function? Here's a picture [link to gyazo picture](https://gyazo.com/aac50d59746bab9c106fecbe454f3e49)

Comment: @TheCodingWombat Don't forget to return `g5` from `genEnemies` so that the caller of `genEnemies` can use the updated `StdGen` and not reuse random numbers -- and update callers to use the same pattern of passing updated `StdGen`s to followup random-number-generation methods!

Comment: How can my `genEnemies` method return `g5`, it already returns an array of moving Enemies. Using a tuple?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat Yep, exactly.

Comment: I got the none-monad version working. I tried creating it with Monads like you suggested: [See this gyazo link](https://gyazo.com/88aecf094358b64f24f185a8bfdac809). I can't find any resources on the internet with good examples. This works when I call the genMoving function once, but the new monad function doesn't return a new generator, so calling the genMoving function again results in the same five random numbers..

Comment: @TheCodingWombat Probably worth another question. But in short: `genMoving'` will need to be in the monad as well. Once in the monad, always in the monad -- at the very top level, your whole game will be in the monad and you'll just feed in the initial random number generator once.