# How to generate a list of random Num elements without IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, io

I need to generate list of random elements without IO monad, is there a way to do it?
I managed to do myself a random list generating function only with IO, here it is:

```
genRandList :: Random a => a -> a -> Int -> IO [a]
genRandList a b n = take n . randomRs (a, b) <$> newStdGen
```

Comment: That's gonna be a bit tricky because randomness is impure.  In other words, you can't have a function of type `a -> a -> Int -> [a]` that produces different output lists when given the same input, because then it wouldn't be a pure function.  Either, you need to pass the random generator as an argument, you need to use IO, or you need to abstract further to, e.g., `MonadRandom`.

Comment: Why can't you use `IO`? How are you trying to use this?

Comment: See [Multiple different random values in the same function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52920457/791604). Does that get you where you need to go? If so, I'll happily mark this as a duplicate of that one. If not, say a bit about why not and we'll be able to write an answer that targets your knowledge gap more precisely.

Comment: Hi, @4castle, thanks for you question! I'm trying to implement parallel Monte-Carlo integrated method.

I am generating 6 batches 10000 elements each (this will be `xs`), and after that I run calculating `ys` in parallel.

The problem with IO is that it hardly paralleling

Comment: Yeah! Thank you very much, @DanielWagner! This will definitely help me!